# Erro ao executar o comando npx react-native init

Tags: react-native, cmd

> Citação

npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "Ricci\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_npx\8724" as it does not contain a package.json file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Vinicius Ricci\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-01-04T18_30_42_929Z-debug.log
Install for [ 'react-native@latest' ] failed with code 1

Answer (score 0):

Este é um problema no nó que é causado pelo espaço em branco no nome do usuário entre o nome e o sobrenome no Windows.

execute o seguinte comando após substituir o nome pelo nome do usuário do Windows no prompt de comando com acesso de administrador

```
npm config set cache "C:\Users\Vinicius~1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache" --global
```